# Find if a user has been "mentioned" in a tweet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I need some guidance on my current obstacle with this application.  If you can point me in the right direction will help.  Basically I have twitter like application with a sql database storing the "tweets" and the users data.The user's nickname always start with a "@".  Now everything is working but i need to add the functionality that if I send a twit and "mentioned" a user, meaning I add @nickname , then that person I mentioned should see it on his messages.  I think I can figure it out, but i'm just confused on how to get started, specifically when I'm getting the "tweet" how can I find a "@" and return the word that contains the "@" ?  The next step should probably be to see if that nickname exists and find the userID by the nickname and update their messages?  Please help me out.

This is what I'm trying.. not working..

```
   HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    String tweet = request.getParameter("tweet");

     ArrayList<User> x= new ArrayList<User>();
     for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++){
        String alias = x.get(i).getAlias();
         if(tweet.contains(alias)){
            try {
               int uid= getUseridByNickName(alias);

                Twit t = new Twit();
                t.setMentionedUserID(uid);

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TwitServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
         }
     }
```

Comment: Please show some code so we know what you've tried so far. You might want to have a look into the JavaDoc for querying an SQL database. You can see that at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html.

Answer (score 0):

To get the username of the mentioned users you could simply use the *indexOf* method:

```
String s = "@user1 @user2 some text";
ArrayList<String> users = new ArrayList<>();
int index = s.indexOf("@");
while(index != -1) {
    users.add(s.substring(index + 1, s.indexOf(" ", index)));
    index = s.indexOf("@", index + 1);
}

users.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Note that this method will work only if the username is followed by a space, otherwise the username will also contain the text between the "@" and the first space it founds (e.g. the tweet "@user1, some text" will return "user1,")